# How to inject Application instance in @Provides?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

My `AppModule` crashes in compile time with error:

```
error: .App cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract .vcs.IGitHubApi getGitHubApi();
                                                       ^
      .App is injected at
          .AppModule.provideOAuth2Interceptor(app)
      .vcs.OAuth2Interceptor is injected at
          .AppModule.provideOkHttpClient(…, oAuth2Interceptor)
      okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
          .AppModule.provideRetrofit(httpClient, …)
      retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
          .AppModule.provideGitHubApi(retrofit)
      .vcs.IGitHubApi is provided at
          .AppComponent.getGitHubApi()
```

Here is my `AppModule` class:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    // other providers

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOAuth2Interceptor(app: App): OAuth2Interceptor {
        return OAuth2Interceptor(app)
    }
}
```

`AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    // other methods

    fun inject(app: App)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun context(context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

And my `App` class where I initialize `AppComponent`:

```
class App: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .context(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

I get that **Dagger** can't find `App` to build `provideOAuth2Interceptor` but I don't know how to inject `App` in provider.

**P.S.** I am learning **Dagger** still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppComponent, you should bind the instance of your `App` class to make it a part of Dagger graph.

```
@Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun context(context: Context): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: App): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
```

and in your App class, provide the instance of App to the component while construction-

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
    .context(this)
    .application(this)
    .build()
    .inject(this)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Although it works as magic for me, I need to learn still how `@BindsInstance` works and what's **Dagger**'s graph...